# how can I implement a socket server that accept an unlimited number of clients?

Tags: php, sockets

I'm implementing a socket server to an unknown number of clients, I found on internet alot of examples where a max number of clients was passed to socket_listen method, but I don't know what could be my number of clients.

If I call socket_listen($sock) without a number of $backlog, it will work for a multiple clients server?

Thanks.

Comment: "Unlimited" is kinda impossible for any socket/server/etc. Do you have any idea what the peak level would be?

Comment: Assuming there is no reason for a client to connect more than once, and you're on IPv4, 4294967296 should be sufficient.

Comment: You could even lower to [3706650624](http://www.bgpexpert.com/addressespercountry.php) :-)

Comment: @zebediah49 this number of connections surely will be sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this natively - but for this [0MQ is the answer](http://vimeo.com/20605470) - see the [chat example from Ian's](https://github.com/ianbarber/ZeroMQ-Talk/tree/master/chat) excellent talk

e.g. Server.php:

```
$ctx = new ZMQContext();
$pub = $ctx->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB);
$pub->bind('tcp://*:5566');
$pull = $ctx->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://*:5567');

while(true) {
    $message = $pull->recv();
    echo "Got ", $message, PHP_EOL;
    $pub->send($message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but let me take a stab at this.

Usually, when you get a connection on a listener, you should create a thread to handle that connection and return to listening. That thread will take up memory on your server, so there cannot be an unlimited number since you don't have unlimited memory. Once the thread (or fork) is done with the connection, the connection should be closed to free up memory and allow another thread.

However, once you reach the limit, new requests will still get a connection, but they will be queued up and won't be handled until the older connections are closed.

Although I do not have any experience in load sharing, I am thinking that requests can be given to other servers to increase the amount of connections that can be held open simultaneously.

This is how TCP works. Perhaps you need a UDP implementation with a publish/subscribe scheme? Since UDP does not have connections, it can publish to many more receivers with less memory.

Comment: your answer was theorical,  but it opened my mind to another research that I'm doing. I'm researching is a way to implement a non I/O blocker (simulation) in php – not related with initial problem. Thanks